# What is the resizing option for inputTextarea component in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, textarea, resizable

I am using JSF2.0 and I have an inputTextArea component and want to prevent the enduser from resizing it.How can I do it.I tried resize="false" but it is not accepting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is to be achieved using the CSS `resize` property which needs to be set to `none`.

E.g.

```
<h:inputTextarea ... style="resize: none" />
```

or, better,

```
<h:inputTextarea ... styleClass="unresizable" />
```

with this in a fullworthy CSS file

```css
.unresizable {
    resize: none;
}
```

The same story applies to the PrimeFaces equivalent `<p:inputTextarea>`. You wasn't exactly clear on which one you were using. Your question title and body implied standard JSF, but you tagged PrimeFaces.